# radare2 stop on lazy loaded library (gdb's stop-on-solib-events)

Tags: debugging, radare2, dynamic-linking

I am running an application and would like to set a breakpoint, as soon as a relevant shared library is loaded. On gdb I can achieve it via

```
set stop-on-solib-events 1
```

I've  been unable to find anything related for radare2. Help would be greatly appreciated.